# Sister seeing off student exchange

Tags: schengen-visas, tourist-visas, proof-of-ties

I'm leaving for a student exchange to France for three months. My sister will be coming along with me for a week. So I have added her name under the list of Airbnb guest members for her accommodation proof. She comes for 7 days only, but the Airbnb booking is for 90 days. Should that be an issue for her visa? She has applied for a tourist visa. She will also tour around with me for the initial days.

Comment: Should not be a problem. The explanation will make sense to any consular.

Comment: Another issue on the same. There are three allowable member guests on my Airbnb booking. I had initially added some other girl's name. And we three have already received our visas. The third girl has backed off and decided to stay at some other location. So I modified this vacancy to my sisters one week stay. I hope this makes sense.. Will that be an issue? Will the consular dig up old documents and might spot a difference? Please help.

Comment: You're worrying too much about it. This is no problem at all.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are truthful and bring all the evidence you need, you should not have a problem with this situation. You sister is staying for 7 days so she will have a booked return flight ticket to prove this. If your sister can also [demonstrate strong ties to her home country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e/92122#92122), then this will help convincing the immigration officer reviewing her application that she has genuine intentions of returning to her home country at the end of her stay. These include, and are not limited to:

- A permanent job
- A house in which one lives / pays mortgage
- Family obligations - children, family members to look after

Strong ties can typically be demonstrated by the [provenance of the funds](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) used as evidence to support one's stay in the country: if there is a regular income of funds from a reputable source then it is likely that the applicant is employed/has stable revenue, both of which indicate a stable lifestyle at home.

In short, do not overthink this. All you have to do is present a strong case supported by truthful evidence.